# How to get doc of a collection with specifc condition from cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using StreamBuilder to get only those docs from the articles collection which satisfies the condition. I used where clause but it is getting all docs and sorting them.
(Note: I want only those docs which satisfy condition in where not all.)
updated code detail: Used another streambuilder to get the ids from the following field in a doc of users collection.

Here how am I doing it:

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('users')
                        .doc(profileScreenController.currentUser.uid)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> futureSnapShot) {
                      if (!futureSnapShot.hasData &&
                          futureSnapShot.data == null) {
                        return SizedBox();
                      }
                      DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                          futureSnapShot.data;
                      return Container(
                        height: screenHeight * 0.32,
                        child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                              .collection('articles')
                              .where('userId',
                                  isEqualTo: documentSnapshot['following'])
                              .snapshots(),
                          builder: (context,
                              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                            print(documentSnapshot['following']);
                            if (!snapshot.hasData &&
                                snapshot.data == null) {
                              return Center(
                                child: Lottie.asset('assets/loading.json'),
                              );
                            }
                            if (snapshot.data.docs.length == 0) {
                              return Center(
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Lottie.asset('assets/no articles.json',
                                        height: 140),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'No body yet',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        color: Theme.of(context)
                                            .textTheme
                                            .headline1
                                            .color,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                            return ListView.builder(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  selectedIndex = index;
                                  DocumentSnapshot todaysArticles =
                                      snapshot.data.docs[index];
                                  return Container(
                                    width: screenWidth * 0.8,
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 6),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                    ),
                                    child: Text(todaysArticles.data() 
                                            ['title'],
                                        ),
                                  );
                                });
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
```

Result: getting doc of both users but not only where username is Guman as my where said.
[image]

My database with 2 docs in articles collection:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.  Since we can't see the value of the variable you pass to `where`, and we can't see the contents of your database, we can't tell what this query is supposed to return.  If a document is being returned that doesn't match your expectations, you should show that here.

Comment: @DougStevenson edited question.. please check now :)

Comment: We still can't see the value of the variable you're passing.  `profileScreenController.followerName`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that the value of `profileScreenController.followerName` is null when creating the stream.

When sending a query like `where('db_field', isEqualTo: null)` the database just returns all the values from the previous query (which in your case is the whole collection).

Please check & debug if the value of `profileScreenController.followerName` is not null when you first open the stream.

Maybe you forgot to use a setState somewhere?